# Navigate to item from FlatList and send the entire item in

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this notes that I am rendering in a FlatList and I want to navigate to the item that is tapped. How can i send in with the navigation the entire item instead of doing `id={id} name={name} etc`, is it possible to navigate to that item and send to the view the entire item?

```
class MyNotes extends Component {
  render() {
    const { notes, navigate } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.view}>
        <FlatList
          numColons={notes.length}
          data={notes}
          renderItem={({ item: { id, name } }) => {
            return (
              <View>
                <Note
                  name={name}
                  id={id}
                  navigate={navigate}
                />
              </View>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Notes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `onPress` handler for your note item and in that you can pass your note item to your view

```
renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <Note
              name={item.name}
              id={item.id}
              navigate={navigate}
              onPress={() => navigate('Note', {...item})}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }}
```

Comment: I get, `Can´t find variable: item`

Comment: Because you are destruction `item` in your `renderItem` method. I am updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could just pass using the [spread operator](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html). So in your case, it would be

```
<Note {...item} />
```